# Switch battery while running

Tags: batteries

Suppose i have a laptop running on battery only and want the ability to switch to another battery without disrupting the laptop temporarily.

The batteries in question are Li-Polymer 7.6V with two positive wires, two negative wires and what i guess are four wires for battery safety and/or sensing current capacity.

I have multiple male/female battery connectors taken from similar motherboards/batteries.

How would you accomplish this? Is it feasible?

Thank you for any help

Comment: Batteries are **dangerous**. They can overheat, ignite, get into a runaway combustion, and explode. People get hurt. If you are not 100% sure of what you are doing (and you obviously aren’t), don’t try to do anything with batteries which deviates from their intended usage. If you want to switch batteries, hibernate, change the battery, and resume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're gonna attempt this, don't wire your supplies directly together in parallel (unless you like smoke).   Use a diode on each, so that the one operating doesn't try to push current into the other.   Also use a couple balancing resistors, so that when they're both running, there is some mechanism to make possible voltage imbalance more forgiving.   Like maybe 0.5 ohm.

Something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsW41p.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I see, thank you. I will try building this probably. Seeing as how there are eight wires, how would you connect the four other wires, or would you disregard them? Just for curiosity, would it be possible to put a capacitor before the load and then use a one way switch to move from one battery to the other while the capacitor keeps the computer running?

Comment: You could put a supercap before the load. Would be bulky but should work. I guess you might also add some circuitry that will shut down the cap supply if the voltage drops to something too low (say in case of a switching malfunction). This is only to avoid damaging the laptop.

Comment: Couldn’t you make a couple of battery packs that you can plug into the laptop where the AC adaptor usually plugs in?  Then the internal battery will take over when the external battery is swapped.

Comment: @raecer   You'll have to map-out what all those wires actually are.   You are right, one or two is likely for temperature.   The extra + and - might be so that the charger can balance the cells  i.e. they operate in series, but if you series-charge batteries, sometimes they end up with different levels of charge on them (depends on their age & other factors).   So to keep the batteries "safe", the charger would need access to each individual cell, not just the whole battery.   In other words, yeah you would ignore the extra wires.  IF I'M RIGHT.   But only you can determine that!

Comment: This one needs more disclaimer and warning about diode drop, and you probably can't afford to have half ohm resistors there and don't need them if the diodes work properly.  Problem is those 4 sense wires matter and should not be disregarded, which implies a much more complicated switching arrangement than could be accomplished with just diodes.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience SOME laptops will run with the battery removed and others do not.  I'm sure it's due to how the unit's power system is designed and I have never seen this "feature" advertised.

The only way I've been able to determine one vs. the other is to try it and see.

But if you are on battery power ONLY and pull the battery, it will go down immediately.  Plug it into an external power source if you want any hope of having this work.

Comment: I'm looking for a circuit or similar that will allow me to switch battery while running without external power. I would be keeping the batteries outside the case.

Comment: @raecer if your laptop works this way this is likely still your best option.  You'd just build a separate power pack to plug in while you swap batteries.